# Like query retrieving all the rows

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have the following query that should use LIKE to search for some content in two fields:

```
string LikeQuery = string.Format(
    "SELECT * FROM tblArticles WHERE ArticleTitle OR ArticleContent LIKE '%{0}%'",
    search);
```

... but it doesn't work: even though the string in `search` does not appear in `ArticleTitle` and `ArticleContent` for any row, still all the rows of the table are retrieved. I wonder how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tblArticles
 WHERE ArticleTitle LIKE '%{0}%' 
    OR ArticleContent LIKE '%{0}%'
```

... i.e, with two separate *logical* expressions. What you're doing now is checking the truthiness of the value in `ArticleTitle` field alone (and only if it's not truthy, the second expression - with LIKE - is evaluated). Apparently, `ArticleTitle` is not empty in all the rows of that table.

As a sidenote, I wonder how is `search` value created here, and wouldn't the resulting query be prone to injection.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ArticleTitle LIKE '%{0}%' OR ArticleContent LIKE '%{0}%'
```

instead of

```
ArticleTitle OR ArticleContent LIKE '%{0}%'
```

But I guess it can vary on db engine